# Template reference variable undefined in radio buttons

Tags: javascript, node.js, angular, typescript

I am having troubles with aplying validations on radio buttons in angular, on other input types, i usualy just create the #templateRefVariable on the input and can then access the NgControl that allows me to use things like the touched property of the control.

What im trying to achieve currently is setting the touched property of the div acording to if any of the radio buttons in the group were touched. (seting it in the div because of css dependencies if it is not in that outer div the validations will not show), but typeCode is always undefined.

```html
<div class="form-group">
    <label>Label</label>
    <div class="btn-group btn-group-toggle w-100"
        [class.ng-invalid]="!viewmodel.typeCode"
        [class.ng-touched]="typeCode?.touched">
        <label *ngFor="let domain of types" class="btn btn-toogle"
            [class.active]="domain.code==viewmodel.typeCode">
            <input type="radio" [(ngModel)]="viewmodel.typeCode"
                #typeCode="ngModel" name="typeCode"
                [value]="domain.code">
            {{domain.description}}
        </label>
    </div>
    <validation-message *ngIf="!viewmodel.typeCode"
        [message]="'Required'"></validation-message>
</div>
```

With invalid i can workarround it by using the information in the view model to see if it was set already but the information on touched is not in the view model.

And i cant do the same for ng-touched because i need to set touched when there is an atempt to submit the form (even if the inputs were not actualy touched).

Any idea why typeCode (templateVariableRef) is undefined while using it in radio buttons ?  i suspect it might be because of there being multiple in the page but i am not sure.

P.S: Using template driven forms

StackBlitz as requested (note errors on console because of typeCode undefined): 
https://angular-5vqi5c.stackblitz.io

Comment: @Chellappanவ edited with stackblitz

Comment: Can you share editable stackblitz link?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is because ngFor is a structural directive and creates a nested template, and therefore these template variable(s) are out of scope.

Would moving your logic inside the ngFor be an option for you e.g.?

```
<div class="btn-group btn-group-toggle w-100"
     [class.ng-invalid]="!viewmodel.typeCode">
  <ng-container *ngFor="let domain of types">
    <div [class.ng-touched]="typeCode?.touched>
      <label class="btn btn-toogle"
             [class.active]="domain.code==viewmodel.typeCode">
        <input type="radio" [(ngModel)]="viewmodel.typeCode"
            #typeCode="ngModel" name="typeCode"
            [value]="domain.code">
        {{domain.description}}
      </label>
    </div>
  </ng-container>
</div>
```

PS. I haven't tested the code above.

Comment: unfortunately no, what that div is doing is in essence is making a group of togable butons that are laid on the radios. but this information that it is because of scoping already helps me atleast understand the cause. thank you

Comment: @Amgg you could still have your btn-group div on the outside and just attempt moving the ng-touched inside, and potentially get away with changing the way your css is applied? FYI, modified my example a bit